# How do detect if there isn't air under my armorstand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an armorstand detect if there isn't air under it and run a command. The problem is, I have many armorstands doing that exact same thing. I thought about inverting the response, but then my next command wouldn't know which one of the armorstands to address. Is there a way, in one command, to determine if there isn't a block where I'm detecting?

Comment: I've now just simply answered the question, but in general you should show what you tried so far so that other people can start there or point out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
/execute @e[type=armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ air 0 scoreboard players tag @s inAir
```

Later you can do something with all other armor stands:

```
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=!inAir] ~ ~ ~ say I'm on the ground.
```